# Ubuntu 20.04 Nvidia drivers tearing issues

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, tearing, nvidia-settings

I switched from x.org drivers to nvidia in order to get better performance from my old and slow nvidia 820M.
 It worked, but i have a constant tearing effects in any application, chrome, vlc and even the app menu in ubuntu.
How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in nvidia x server settings

- X Server Display Configuration
- Choose your monitor
- Advanced
- Force Full Composition
  Pipeline